# Firebase rule to give read access to the recipient of the message

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-security, angularfire2

I am trying to make a mobile application using Ionic 2 + angularFire2.

Basically my database will consist of users and messages. Users will be authenticated via email and password.

Users will exchange messages by:

1. Searching if the recipient email is valid/registered
2. Sending the message to the recipient
3. The message is readable **only** by the **recipient**

Sample Data:

```
"messages" : {
    // message key
    "-KbUpdXdFT6ggEqCXDd5" : {
        "data" : "Lorem Ipsum",
        "recipient" : "john.doe@gmail.com",
        "sender" : "bill.doe@gmail.com"
    },
    "-KbUr1_8AakzKjdwfmny" : {
        "data" : "Some message",
        "recipient" : "john.doe@gmail.com",
        "sender" : "bill.doe@gmail.com"
    },
}
"users": {
    // users key
    "OpYYjG3iJsprgPNmhrNZ: {
        "email": "john.doe@gmail.com"
    },
    "bwEd48upa0e7h5ghKEpo":{
        "email": "bill.doe@gmail.com"
    }
 }
```

Sample rules:

```
"rules": {
    "messages":{   
        // everyone is allowed to write new messages
        ".write": "auth != null",            
        "$message": {
            // read only if you are an authenticated user and your email is the same as the recipient 
            ".read": "auth != null && data.child('recipient').val() == auth.token.email"
     },
     "users":{
         ".read": "auth != null"         
     }   
 }
```

With the rules set up, user John Doe would call this query to get the list of received messages:

```
messages = this.af.database.list('messages',{
        query:{
            orderByChild: 'recipient',
            equalTo: "john.doe@gmail.com"
        }
    });
```

**PROBLEM:**
I keep getting the "Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data." error.

Im guessing it has something to do with:

```
".read": "auth != null && data.child('recipient').val() == auth.token.email"
```

I tried various other rules, but with no success. Even considered going with a more nested design with messages being under users but that seemed to be considered an anti-pattern.

Any help, advice or tutorials would be welcomed! Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your user email adress is stored in your auth payload? 
This is different from storing it in a users table. If it is not in the auth payload, that might be the issue. What is in your token varies depending on what authentication method you are using.

Comment: Hey arneson, thanks for the reply. 
I am not entirely sure if the token has the email variable for the password method.
The documentation does state that it should contain a email value for certain accounts [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken)

Comment: What authentication method are you using?

Comment: I am using the password based authentication method. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is related to a very widely discussed subject:

**Firebase rules are not filters.**

The main thing is, you can't use rules to filter the way you want to, if you have access to one child of a node and not its sibling you will get an error trying to read the parent node.

See: [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)

**Solution**
One solution is to change your structure to look something like this:

```
"messages" : {
    // Each recipient has his own child node
    "user-id-of-john-doe" : {
        "KbUpdXdFT6ggEqCXDd5" : {
            "data" : "Lorem Ipsum",
            "recipient" : "john.doe@gmail.com",
            "sender" : "bill.doe@gmail.com"
        },
        "-KbUr1_8AakzKjdwfmny" : {
            "data" : "Some message",
            "recipient" : "john.doe@gmail.com",
            "sender" : "bill.doe@gmail.com"
        },
    }
}
```

Where John Doe is your recipient.

Using this approach each user has his own messages sub node which he can be granted access to read, into which other users add their messages to said user. If you want to observe the messages received by a particular user you simply observe the node

```
messages/userId-or-email-or-whatever-unique-identifier-you-use/
```

Comment: I see, so would the solution be to put the messages under a different structure? As in users -> keys that would have write access for authenticated users, but read rights only for the user who is the owner?

Comment: Seems that maybe firebase doesn't allow certain characters in the path such as "." so I'm guessing I should switch to the user uid as the path in the new structure.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help arneson!

Comment: No problem, I changed my answer so people won't make that mistake, thanks.